# Turn df column into vector and use as input instead of having to write out the same info with a c()

Tags: r

I am very new to r and coding in general. So far, I have done two projects that are big for me and used several hours to finish. In both projects I had the situation that I needed a vector as an input like this `c("Washington", "Dakota", "New York")`

In both projects, the vector consisted of 20+ entries. The information, such as Washington or Dakota, that I need to write in the vector, is also available as a column in a dataframe.

I basically had to type down everything that was already in a column again. Since I am a bit lazy sometimes and would rather spend my time and concentration on finding the right functions etc, I wondered if it is possible to turn the column of a dataframe into a vector and then just call the vector as input, instead o having to type everyrthing again.

I tried turning the df column into a vector with `as.vector`, but it did not work out, when I replaced `c()` with the name of the vector.

Is that not possible at all or how I have to write it?

Answer (score 0):

A data.frame is a *list* of vectors that are all the same length. You can access a specific vector with `$` or `[[`.

Example: `iris$Species` or more safely `iris[['Species']]`.